# How to make property implemented only by some child classes be accessible via parent class?

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class

Let's say I have following code:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{    
  public Transmission MyTransmission;
  public int NumberOfWheels;
  public int NumberOfSeats;
  public int Weight;
  public int TopSpeed; //etc.
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
  public int SteeringWheelSize = 10;
}

public class Truck : Vehicle
{
  public int SteeringWheelSize = 20;
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{

}

public class FourWheelTransmission
{
  public Vehicle ParentVehicle;
  public Transmission(Vehicle vehicle)
  {
    ParentVehicle = vehicle;
    //here, I want to access the SteeringWheelSize from its ParentVehicle object.
  }
}
```

To accomplish the goal in the last comment, what should be the best method? Of course, one way would be making two abstract classes: "public abstract class TwoWheelVehicle" and "public abstract class FourWheelVehicle", but what if we don't want to repeat all the similar properties common in both FourwheelVehicle and TwoWheelVehicle, is there any other way to allow FourWheelTransmission class to access its vehicle's SteeringWheelSize?

Comment: Both `TwoWheelVehicle` and `FourWheelVehicle` could extend `Vehicle` and inherit its properties. `FourWheelVehicle` will declare `SteeringWheelSize`. I'm not sure if you really need `TwoWheelVehicle`.

Comment: I've updated title (from absolutely generic one) - see if it matches your intention.

Answer (score 3):

How about that:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{    
  public Transmission MyTransmission;
  public int NumberOfWheels;
  public int NumberOfSeats;
  public int Weight;
  public int TopSpeed; //etc.
}

public abstract class FourWheelVehicle : Vehicle
{
  public int SteeringWheelSize;
}

public class Car : FourWheelVehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        SteeringWheelSize = 10;
    }
}

public class Truck : FourWheelVehicle
{
    public Truck()
    {
        SteeringWheelSize = 20;
    }
}


public class FourWheelTransmission
{
  public FourWheelVehicle ParentVehicle;
  public Transmission(FourWheelVehicle vehicle)
  {
    ParentVehicle = vehicle;
    //here, I want to access the SteeringWheelSize from its ParentVehicle object.
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably *every* FourWheelVehicle should specify a size, so why not put that in the constructor for FourWheelVehicle? You can then make it read-only. (I'd also strongly recommend avoiding it being a public field, too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You're absolutely right! But the main thing here is the new class, between `Car`/`Truck` and `Vehicle`.

Comment: Right. As one option, at least - an interface being the other one.

Answer (score 2):

Without `Bike` in the picture, it would sound to me like `Vehicle` should have a `SteeringWheelSize` which is assigned a value in the constructor, called by the subclass.

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int SteeringWheelSize { get; private set; }
    ...

    protected Vehicle(int steeringWheelSize)
    {
        SteeringWheelSize = steeringWheelSize;
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car() : base(20)
    {
    }
}

...
```

However, you now have a problem: `Bike` doesn't have a steering wheel, so your model no longer fits. If you want to be able to model both a `Bike` and a `Car`, you perhaps need another class between `Vehicle` and `Car`, and put the `SteeringWheelSize` member there instead - then `FourWheelTransmission` would be passed that instead. (This is effectively MarcinJuraszek's answer, although I would give the new intermediate class a constructor accepting the steering wheel size as above.)

That's then slightly awkward in terms of using up the one shot of inheritance - you're effectively deciding that "whether or not it has a steering wheel" is the one important distinction; you can't make a *different* distinction elsewhere in the same way, due to the lack of multiple inheritance of implementation in C#.

Alternatively, both `Car` and `Truck` could implement an *interface* saying that they've got a steering wheel, and `FourWheelTransmission` could use that instead. At that point you *could* still use an intermediate abstract class, but you wouldn't have to:

```
public interface ISteerable
{
    int SteeringWheelSize { get; }
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    // Properties here
}

public class Car : Vehicle, ISteerable
{
    public SteeringWheelSize { get { return 20; } }
}

...

public class FourWheelTransmission
{
    // We know we can safely cast this to ISteerable
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    private FourWheelTransmission(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    public static FourWheelTransmission<T> FromSteerableVehicle(T vehicle)
        where T : Vehicle, ISteerable
    {
    }
}
```

Note the slight awkwardness here - we can't express to the compiler that `FourWheelTransmission` will have a single variable which is both a subclass of `Vehicle` *and* an implementation of `ISteerable`, unless we make `FourWheelTransmission` itself generic and use constraints. I've got a workaround above, where you can only *construct* an instance of `FourWheelTransmission` based on such a type, but without `FourWheelTransmission` being generic. If `Vehicle` were an interface instead, then `ISteerable` could extend `IVehicle`.

Also please note that this *requires* you to use properties rather than public fields - interfaces can't specify fields. I think this is a good thing anyway - I dislike public fields intensely, as they're exposing an *implementation detail* through the public API.

Comment: But there is a `Bike` that inherits from `Vehicle` and have no `SteeringWheel` at all :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, I hadn't spotted that before, but I've now edited.

Comment: But a bike has handlebars and that also has a size. Then you might have a futuristic car which uses a remote control.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Indeed, but I think by this point we've moved a long way away from the OP's question. I suspect in the real code, he's not modelling vehicles at all.

Comment: haha, yea my real code is more complicated and I'm trying to gather all the possible solutions to see which one is most suitable. thanks guys :)

Comment: @user2503766: Read the middle section of my answer carefully, as it will give a hint as to whether the "intermediate abstract class" or the "extra interface" approach is more suitable. Is the presence of a steering wheel the most fundamental division between types here that merits having an intermediate class? It's a simpler solution than the interface one, but you can only do it once.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is:

You can give a default value to two wheeler steering size also (say -1) and use if conditions in the logic wherever steering size is used.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an interface.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {    
  public Transmission MyTransmission  { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
  public int Weight { get; set; }
  public int TopSpeed { get; set; } //etc.
}

public interface ISteeringWheelVehicle {
    int SteeringWheelSize { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle, ISteeringWheelVehicle {
    public Car() {
        SteeringWheelSize = 10;
    }

    public int SteeringWheelSize { get; set; }
}

public class Truck : Vehicle, ISteeringWheelVehicle {
    public Truck() {
        SteeringWheelSize = 20;
    }

    public int SteeringWheelSize { get; set; }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle {
}

public class FourWheelTransmission {
    public Vehicle ParentVehicle;
    public Transmission(Vehicle vehicle) {
        ParentVehicle = vehicle;

        if (ParentVehicle is ISteeringWheelVehicle) {
            var steeringWheelSize = ((ISteeringWheelVehicle)ParentVehicle).SteeringWheelSize;
        }
    }
}
```